# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException in the Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I started a Spring boot application and so far I have the minimal amount of code besides the design. The entities and domain classes are provided below,

The `Authority` class,

```
public class Authority implements GrantedAuthority {

    private final String authority;

    public Authority(String authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The `Role` class,

```
@Entity

    public class Role {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int roleId;
    }
```

The `UserRole` class,

```
@Entity
public class UserRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
}
```

The `User` class,

```
@Entity

    public class User {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;
    }
```

The security config class is provided,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return null;
    }

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
            "/css/**",
            "/js/**",
            "/image/**",
            "/fonts/**",
            "/",
            "/login",
            "/forgetpassword",
            "/newuser"
    };


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity
                .authorizeRequests().
        /*  antMatchers("/**").*/
                antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).
                permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable().cors().disable()
                .formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error")
            /*.defaultSuccessUrl("/")*/
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout").deleteCookies("remember-me").permitAll()
                .and()
                .rememberMe();
    }


    /*
    * global configuration for the user security
    * */

}
```

The controller class is provided,

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "login")
    public String login() {
        return "account";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "forgetpassword")
    public String forgetPassword() {
        return "account";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "newuser")
    public String newUserPost() {
        return "account";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "newuser")
    public String newUser() {
        return "profile";
    }
}
```

The Spring boot started class,

```
@SpringBootApplication

    public class EcommerceApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(EcommerceApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

I stated to get the error,

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryUserDetailsManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/AuthenticationManagerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager]: Factory method 'inMemoryUserDetailsManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager.<init>([Lorg/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails;)V
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: You're using incompatible versions of libraries, i.e. the Spring boot version you're using and the spring-security version you're using are not compatible.

Comment: Yes, the issue is solve for now